# Is there a way in powershell to catch ALL named parameters

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

Consider this:

```
Function Foo 
{
    param(
        #????
    )
}
```

I want to call Foo like this:

```
Foo -Bar "test"
```

Without it blowing up that I don't have a $bar param specified. Is that possible? :)

Update:

I want this to work:

```
Function IfFunctionExistsExecute
{
    param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$func, [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$args)
    begin 
    {
        # ...
    }
    process
    {
        if(Get-Command $func -ea SilentlyContinue)
        {
            & $func $args   # the amperersand invokes the function instead of just printing the variable
        }
        else
        {
            # ignore
        }       
    }
    end
    {
        # ...
    }
}


Function Foo
{
    param([string]$anotherParam)
    process 
    {
        $anotherParam
    }
}

IfFunctionExistsExecute Foo -Test "bar"
```

This gives me:

```
IfFunctionExistsExecute : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Test'.
At C:\PSTests\Test.ps1:35 char:34
+ IfFunctionExistsExecute Foo -Test <<<<  "bar"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [IfFunctionExistsExecute], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,IfFunctionExistsExecute
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest two alternatives.

First: you may want to consider passing whole function + it's parameters as scriptblock parameter to your ifFunction...

OR: use ValueFromRemainingArguments:

```
function Test-SelfBound {
param (
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        HelpMessage = 'Help!'
    )]
    [string]$First,
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true
    )]
    [Object[]]$MyArgs
)

$Arguments = foreach ($Argument in $MyArgs) {
    if ($Argument -match '^-([a-z]+)$') {
        $Name = $Matches[1]
        $foreach.MoveNext() | Out-Null
        $Value = $foreach.Current
        New-Variable -Name $Name -Value $Value
        $PSBoundParameters.Add($Name,$Value) | Out-Null
    } else {
        $Argument
    }
}
    $PSBoundParameters | Out-Default
    "Positional"
    $Arguments

}

Test-SelfBound -First Test -Next Foo -Last Bar Alfa Beta Gamma
```

In this case I use $MyArgs to store everything besides my mandatory parameter 'First'. Than some simple if will tell me if it's named parameter (-Next, -Last) or positional (Alfa, Beta, Gamma). This way you can have both advantages of advanced functions binding (whole [Parameter()] decoration) AND leave room for $args-style parameters too.

Comment: If I call `Test-SelfBound -out foo` I get an error: _Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'out' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -OutVariable -OutBuffer_ . And if I call `Test-SelfBound -d foo` it doesn't declare a variable called "d", but one called "Debug" :-( I guess this will happen for all [common parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx)
:-(

Comment: True: function definition makes it advanced function (triggered by `[Parameter()]` decoration), and as such it will always have common parameters defined.

Comment: --$Argument -match '^-([\S]+)$'-- will be more better. We need white space only. Best sampe

Answer (score 3):

You could use the $args variable in your function which is an array of the arguments passed into the function, e.g.

```
function Foo()
{
    Write-Output $args[0];
    Write-Output $args[1];
}

Foo -Bar "test"
```

Outputs:

```
-Bar
test
```

Comment: rather than containing all arguments passed into the function $args will contain all unbound arguments